# Base operand has non-pointer type..but it is a pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operand

I'm working on a C++ project that deals with graphs. It has a lot of functionality related to a class "Node" and a class "Edge."

At first, an Edge stored copies of its starting node and its ending node; something like:

```
class Edge{
...
private:
  Node m_start, m_end;
...
}
```

To make certain graph modification functions more efficient, I decided to make the Edge class store pointers to the start and end nodes instead:

```
class Edge{
  ...
  private:
    Node* m_start, m_end;
  ...
}
```

I thus made adjustments in the cpp files/related functions to ensure proper access (e.g., changing `.`s to `->`s). One example is in a printing function:

```
void
Edge::Print(ostream& _os){
  _os << "EdgeID = " << m_id << endl
  << "Connects nodes: " << m_start->GetIndex() << " and " << m_end->GetIndex() << endl;
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get this message (and similar ones for the same kinds of changes elsewhere):

```
Models/Edge.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Edge::Print(std::ostream&) const’:
Models/Edge.cpp:32: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘const Node’
```

[where 32 is the line in the example above that starts with `<< "Connects nodes: "`]

What is going on here? m_start IS a pointer, as far as I can tell! Might there be something wrong in assignment somewhere? The `GetIndex()` function being called in the example looks like this, and the same error occurs with or without the `const`:

```
int GetIndex() const { return m_index; }  //in Node.h
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've shot yourself in both feet. It should be:

```
Node* m_start, * m_end;
```

Next time, just pay the extra screen line and write:

```
Node * m_start;
Node * m_end;
```

You'll be doing everyone a favour.

Answer (score 3):

```
Node* m_start, m_end;
```

This declares `m_start` as a `Node*`, but it declares `m_end` as a `Node`. The code to make them both pointers would look like this:

```
Node* m_start, *m_end;
```